# Cost of event vs Storage

Tags: gas, gas-price, gas-estimate

I have 2 approaches to store result of an election in the contract. I can store the result corresponding to different candidates.

1. I do some computation and keep on updating the storage in the blockchain.
2. I do some computation and keep on updating the memory in the blockchain and then finally trigger a event.

This function is to be called only once.
Will the 2nd approach save some gas value?
Will computation cost in the 2nd approach is 0? because we not storing permanen any value in the blockchain.

Comment: Memory has usage cost, it is cheap but it is not zero. Also if you use too much the cost increases quadratically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The second approach will not have a computation cost of zero(0). Running computations on the blockchain that do not store any values will still incur a cost.
- There will be some cost to the second approach. Events are generally cheaper than storage on ETH but not free.
- Keep in mind that if you fire off an event from your Solidity code that event will get stored on the chain but the event data won't be accessible from your Solidity code. If you can build your voting system without needing to read the results from Solidity than the second approach makes more sense.